# how to share a stored object between multiple jsp pages?

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I'd like to share an object after loading it from disk between multiple JSP pages and sessions. So far the closest solution I found was this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="inventory" class="shared.Inventory" scope="application" />
```

However this limits me to using a new bean. I'd like to load an object that was saved to disk when the application starts and share it across all JSP pages.

Comment: That's the right approach. Please explain your problem in more details.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That approach only allows me to set properties on the new "inventory" object, however, I already have an object for the Inventory class saved on disk that I would like to load and share across all JSP pages.

Comment: So you would like to load the object when the application starts and share it across all JSP files?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's correct. Sorry for the confusion, I probably should have worded it that way originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should load the object when the application starts by using [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). Then, store it in application scope.

```
public class AppListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //application is deployed
        //create your object and load it
        Inventory inventory = ...
        //get the application context
        ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
        //store the object in application scope
        servletContext.setAttribute("inventory", inventory);
    }
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //application is undeployed
    }
}
```

Then, register the filter in web.xml accordingly:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>package.where.you.store.AppListener</listenerclass>
</listener>
```

After deploying your application, the bean would be available for use in all pages for all users and can be accessed through Expression Language:

```
${inventory.someField}
```